# URL percent encoded (hex) characters in .htaccess

Tags: htaccess

There is an old page with a space in the filename, and this is no longer found on the website. So I need to redirect this page to another page using a 301 redirect in .htaccess.

If I place the filename directly into .htaccess (eg. `Bouquets%20%26%20Loose.html`), the redirect does not work. If I escape the `%` sign(eg. `Bouquets\%20\%26\%20Loose.html`), the redirect still does not work.

How do I get this redirect to work in `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer: it is to enclose the URL in " and use the non-encoded characters.   eg:

```
Redirect 301 "/Bouquets & Loose.html" http://...
```